# Angular CLI v6.0.8 won't install

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

I've installed NodeJS via PPA on Ubuntu 18.04. However when running `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` I get the error at the bottom of this post.

I am using node v10.6.0 and npm v6.1.0. I have tried these commands, with no luck:

```
A) sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
B) npm install -g @angular/cli (no sudo)
C) sudo npm install -g angular-cli --unsafe-perm=true
```

One thing I noticed was that in case C it actually installs and works when running as sudo. But it doesn't work as a regular user ("bash: ng: command not found").

I have checked my PATH env variable and have confirmed that the result of `npm bin -g` (/usb/bin) is indeed in my PATH for all users.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
me@laptop:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
[sudo] password for me:
/usr/bin/ng -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng-update-message.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall: `node ./bin/ng-update-message.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Try using node 8.11.3, and see if that works better.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried 8.11.3 (current LTS version) and still no luck. Same error :\

Comment: Can you share your node and npm versions?
node -v
npm -v
@Kidquick

Comment: node v10.6.0 and npm v6.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT! After much digging around I realized this was a permissions issue. A system-wide **umask** in the PAM module (Ubuntu) was set to create files and folders with more restrictive permissions than usual. This is what I did to get back to normal and get Angular CLI installed:

`sudo vi /etc/pam.d/common-session`

Then change this line: `session optional pam_umask.so umask=077`

To this: `session optional pam_umask.so`

Reboot, then: `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Et Voilà!